# Changing API level Promblems

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I am currently trying to add an ActionBar into my Android application. I put in the following code:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

However, this creates an error in Eclipse. It tells me "Call requires API level 11 (Current min is 8)"

I changed my `minsdkversion`, but that doesn't seem to change anything. This is what it is is in the Manifest.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

**EDIT:** I have found that cleaning the project individually (not the entire Workspace) after each and every save allows me to run, though I would hardly call this a solution.

Comment: Have you tried simply re-running Lint?

Comment: I believe I have. Perhaps I am doing it incorrectly. How would you recommend I go about re-running Lint?

Comment: try `clean & rebuilt`

Comment: I don't know how to do this.

Comment: The problem seems to have solved itself... somehow... I minimized Eclipse for a few hours. When I got back, the problem was no longer shown.

Comment: And it's back again after saving a few more times.

Answer (score 0):

The case may be that Eclipse is still showing an error from the last time Lint was run on your project. Click Window --> Show View --> Other... and type "lint" into the search box. Click "Lint Warnings" and hit OK to add the Lint View to your workspace. From there, click the Refresh button to re-run Lint.

Comment: I tried this, and it came up with many more errors, many of which weren't even in files I had written... Among the errors, there is still the one I described in the question.